# Zamzar API doesn't work with python dict

Tags: python, json

So i was testing the [Zamzar API](https://developers.zamzar.com/docs#section-Obtain_an_API_key), which everything worked just fine until i decided to change the manually execution flow where by, instead of running a single script like getting a file ID and pasting the ID manually to the downloading script and run it separately, all should be run in a single script.

The problem is, the script works fine but the downloaded file ends up being corrupted, but if i do everything manually everything seems to work fine and the file downloaded never gets corrupted.

Here are the codes:

```
import json
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
try:
    from Tkinter import * 
except ImportError:
    from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

api_key = 'xxxxf7ed51289f62acc556e1026299xxxxxxxxxx'

## Test inspection
endpoint = "https://sandbox.zamzar.com/v1/formats/docx"
resp1 = requests.get(endpoint, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(api_key, ''))

json_str1 = json.dumps(resp1.json())
print (json.loads(json_str1))

## Start a conversion job

endpointC = "https://sandbox.zamzar.com/v1/jobs"
Tk().withdraw()
source_file = filedialog.askopenfilename()
target_format = "pdf"

file_content = {'source_file': open(source_file, 'rb')}
data_content = {'target_format': target_format}
res = requests.post(endpointC, data=data_content, files=file_content, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(api_key, ''))

json_str2 = json.dumps(res.json())
resp2 = json.loads(json_str2)

## Check the completed job

job_id = (resp2['id'])
endpointJ = "https://sandbox.zamzar.com/v1/jobs/{}".format(job_id)

respo = requests.get(endpointJ, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(api_key, ''))

json_str3 = json.dumps(respo.json())
resp3 = json.loads(json_str3)

## Download the converted file
file_id = (resp3['source_file']['id'])
local_filename = 'tmp/why.pdf'
endpointD = "https://sandbox.zamzar.com/v1/files/{}/content".format(file_id)

respon = requests.get(endpointD, stream=True, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(api_key, ''))

try:
  with open(local_filename, 'wb') as f:
    for chunk in respon.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
      if chunk:
        f.write(chunk)
        f.flush()

    print ("File downloaded")

except IOError:
  print ("Error")
```

Now i was wondering does it have something to do with json to python dict conversation?
Or is there anything that i am doing wrong?

Comment: Is that your real api key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm one of the lead developers for the Zamzar API so should be able to help here.

It looks like the issue here is that you are grabbing the ID to the **source_file** when you setup the code to download your converted file, so you are actually just downloading your input file again and saving that as a PDF (which is why it appears to be "corrupted"):

```
## Download the converted file
file_id = (resp3['source_file']['id'])
```

When [retrieving details](https://developers.zamzar.com/docs#section-Retrieving_a_job) about a conversion job the converted file ID can be found in the **target_files** array of the JSON response:

```
{
    "id" : 15,
    "key" : "XXXX",
    "status" : "successful",
    "sandbox" : true,
    "created_at" : "2013-10-27T13:41:00Z",
    "finished_at" : "2013-10-27T13:41:13Z",
    "source_file" : {"id":2,"name":"portrait.gif","size":90571},
    "target_files" : [{"id":3,"name":"portrait.png","size":15311}],
    "target_format" : "png",
    "credit_cost" : 1
}
```

So you should modify your code to grab the file ID from this field instead, like so:

```
## Download the converted file
file_id = (resp3['target_files'][0]['id'])
```

However, you need to make sure the job has finished converting first as this field is only populated when the job is done. So you should extend your code to check for this in a loop first - something like:

```
def check_job(id):
    print ("Checking if job is finished")
    endpoint = "https://sandbox.zamzar.com/v1/jobs/{}".format(job_id)
    response = requests.get(endpoint, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(api_key, ''))
    return json.loads(json.dumps(response.json()))

## Check the completed job
job_id = (resp2['id'])
job_status = ""
job_details = ""
while job_status != "successful" :
     job_details = check_job(job_id)
     job_status = (job_details['status'])
     print (job_status)
     time.sleep(2) 
     if job_status == "successful" :
         break
```

You can then proceed to download the converted file:

```
file_id = (job_details['target_files'][0]['id'])
local_filename = '/tmp/why.pdf'
endpointD = "https://sandbox.zamzar.com/v1/files/{}/content".format(file_id)
```

As an aside we'd recommend not publishing your API key publicly - it could be seen and abused by anyone that reads this question. In general it's good practice to just hash out the key if you are posting sample code of this kind.

To prevent abuse we have regenerated a new key for you which you can find in your API dashboard at https://developers.zamzar.com/user

Comment: First, thanks fro the answer,what a noob i am :) , cant even detect that i'm grabbing a wrong id! Also sorry for the API publication, lesson learnt.